# Multiple sliders reacting to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Newbie here.
I am making one of my first project and I want to have sliders for different people in it (normal people, workers, farmers etc.) but I don´t know how to put multiple sliders and how to get all of them working. I took the code from W3schools and changed some things but it seems that I have broken it and I don´t know what to do with it. I want to have 2 sliders both working and when one slider goes up and the other goes down (assigning people to thier work). Here is my code (I don´t know if it would be to any help)

```js
        var people = 100;
        var workers = 0;
        document.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (document.readyState == "complete") {

                var slider = document.getElementById("sliderWorkers");
                var output = document.getElementById("workers").innerHTML = workers;
                output.innerHTML = workers;



                slider.oninput = function () {
                    output.innerHTML = this.value;
                }

                /*################################################################*/
                var slider2 = document.getElementById("sliderPeople");
                var output = document.getElementById("people").innerHTML = people;
                output.innerHTML = slider.value;


                slider.oninput = function () {
                    output.innerHTML = this.value;
                }


            }
        }
        setInterval(function () {


            document.getElementById("people").innerHTML = people;
            document.getElementById("workers").innerHTML = workers;
        }, 100000);
```

```css
        .slider, .slider2 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 10%;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider2::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1>Population range slider</h1>

    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="sliderWorkers">
        <p>Value wokers: <div id="workers"></div>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" class="slider2" id="sliderPeople">
        <p>Value people: <div id="people"></div>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) and [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in order to start your task when the dom is ready.

After you [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) in order to select all your range elements and for each one its required an event handler.

Inside this event handler you can update the value.

Note: P + DIV now is P with a SPAN inside.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    document.querySelectorAll('[type="range"]').forEach(function (ele) {
        ele.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
            this.parentElement.querySelector('span').textContent = this.value;
            var next = this.closest('div').nextElementSibling;
            if (next.tagName != 'DIV') {
                next = this.closest('div').previousElementSibling;
            }
            next.querySelector('[type="range"]').value = 100 - +this.value;
            next.querySelector('span').textContent = 100 - +this.value;
        });
        // start with an initial value.....simultating an input...
        ele.parentElement.querySelector('span').textContent = ele.value;
    });
})
```

```css
.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 10%;
    height: 7px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1>Population range slider</h1>

<div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="sliderWorkers">

    <p>Value wokers: <span id="workers"></span></p>

</div>
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" class="slider" id="sliderPeople">

    <p>Value people: <span id="people"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! This did help me but I still wonder how can I make them so that when I have more workers the number of people goes down and vice versa

Comment: I mean something like those people are just unemployed guys. So when you move the worker slider up the unemployed "people" bar goes down. I would like to do it trough variable but I dont really know what most of the stuff means...

Comment: thank you so much! I don´t know if I will be able to get some more sliders working but at least I will have two of them :D . Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it possible to have both sliders moving at the same time? I have just spotted that only one moves and the second is just there. After you do something with the second one it just changes the var a lot if you know what I mean. I understand if you wouldnt like to re-work it but I would be gratefull.

Comment: there is a bug, where when you move the bottom slider (people one). It works here but not on a page. The bug is on this line " if (next.tagName != 'DIV') { " . Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null

Comment: it's a matter of your html. Please, ask another question. We cannot continue with comments. Sorry.....